# Cannot install Ubuntu on HP omen 15 laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I bought the new HP omen 15 laptop with windows 10 x64 pre-installed and I have problems while installing linux. I made 2 partitions on my laptop . A 15Gb partition on my ssd for "/" and another 85Gb on my HDD for "/home" . Then I disabled fast startup in bios, I disabled the secure boot. Made a live usb using rufus for uefi mode. I'm stuck on the load screen for Ubuntu as well as for fedora. I tried with different usb sticks also!

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try on GRUB screen press "e" to edit ubuntu boot config. And add "nomodeset" before "quiet splash". Works for me

Comment: Don't bump threads with an answer. This is useless

Comment: Sorry. edited :)

Comment: It doesn't sound like OP has even reached the boot screen (I have been wrong before) so how does this answer the question?

Comment: Stuck on the load screen. Not  boot (GRUB) screen. Read carefully the question and answer

Comment: This answer might work anyway (**maybe**, but it's worth a try). Boot from the Ubuntu live USB, and immediately after the BIOS/UEFI splash screen during boot, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the Esc key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen.

Answer (score 0):

Press 'e' to edit grub, after 'quiet splash' add 'pci=nommconf modprobe.blacklist=nouveau'.
Once you boot install nVidia drivers and install Grub Customizer to always write 'pci=nommconf' while booting.

I have an Omen 15 DC0004NQ.
That's how I fixed it.
If you need help, search google for 'Medium Ubuntu install HP Omen 15' and you'll find an article specially made for this laptop.

Comment: Please check answer to at least say if it does not work..